# Create multiple aliases for localhost addresses on different ports

Tags: server, localhost, alias, port-forwarding

I have some webapps running on my localhost that I can access by my web browser at different ports.

For example I have an IPython notebook server running on port 8888 (I can access it at `http://localhost:8888`), and a small flask app that listens on port 9000.

I know that I can set an alias for localhost by modifying `/etc/hosts`, but what I would like to achieve here is to have different aliases for the different ports.

For example I would like to open my browser and use `http://notebooks/`instead of `http://localhost:8888` and `http://flaskapp` rather than `http://localhost:9000`.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll have to use either some form of iptables destination-based forwarding rule, or use [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html) or [nginx as a proxy](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html). For `nginx`:

```
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

Create a [virtual server configuration](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server) of the form:

```
server {
    server_name notebooks;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8888;
        proxy_redirect default;
    }
    access_log /var/log/nginx/notebook-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/notebook-error.log;
}
```

This can be done by editing the default site (`/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`), or by creating a new file in that directory (`/etc/nginx/sites-available/notebook`, for example). Use your favourite editor with admin privileges (`sudo vim`, `sudo -H gedit`, etc.).

Then enable the site by creating a link in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`, if it doesn't already exist:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-{available,enabled}/default
# or, if you created a new file:
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-{available,enabled}/notebook
```

Restart `nginx`:

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

Edit `/etc/hosts` so that you have an alias with the same name used for `server_name` in the above configuration.

You can create many more such virtual servers for proxying to various ports.

---

I'm not too sure of my iptables-fu, but some simple redirections seem to work well for me. For example, with a simple Python web server (`python3 -m http.server 8888`):

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d notebooks --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8888
```

The command is easy to understand:

- `-A OUTPUT -p tcp` to match outgoing TCP traffic.
- `-d notebooks` and `--dport 80` to match the destination hostname and port. The port isn't necessary here, since you'll likely be using only one port anyway.
- `-j REDIRECT --to-ports 8888` to use the REDIRECT chain, with `8888` as the target port for redirection. You can only use this chain with the `nat` table.
- An entry for `notebooks` should exist in `/etc/hosts` *before* you apply this rule.

Comment: Hi muru, could you please add a few lines on the use of iptables as well? I'd rather not install a web server just for aliasing purposes

Comment: @lucacerone see update. I'd expect this to break with an application that does redirection and such, and I typically use a  proxy such as [redsocks](http://darkk.net.ru/redsocks/) in combination with iptables when I have to.